# Increase font-size dropdown menu, Safari and Firefox. Rails and CSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to increase the font size from the text on the dropdown I used inline styles on the **div.select** but It just works on Chrome, in safari and firefox just can see increased the placeholder from the *select* tag, but not the content of the dropdown. I would like to know how I can edit the **options** tag inside the dropdown for Safari and Firefox so I can increase the font size of the dropdown content in every common browser.

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-xs-12">
   <div class="select-wrapper">
       <div class="select" style="font-size:30px;">
         <% options = ["Please select"] + Company::COMPANY_TYPES%>
         <%= company_form.select :company_type, options.collect {|type| [type, type.downcase]} %>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't style native select dropdowns with css, they are OS specific.

Comment: @Kunsang doesn't exist any kind gem or library to edit this text?